телеграм бот присваивает конкретную ссылку пользователю
Помогите пожалуйста! Как сделать так, чтобы бот присваивал пользователям ссылку, а потом другие пользователи, переходя по ней, через того же бота могли отправлять сообщения владельцу ссылки. программирую на python телеграм бота если что.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
